# Swift canceling rest of function

Tags: swift, function

Remember the good old days when End would stop everything and goto would take you somewhere without coming back? Well, "End" is essentially what I am trying to do, is cancel the rest of a function. 
ie.

```
 func function () {
      x = 5
      //code to cancel and stop function
      x = 0
 }
```

I want this to readout x = 5.  The reason I want to do this is because I have numerous functions called from within functions.  To keep it simple, is there anyway for this to happen?

Comment: Are you looking for the `return` statement ??

Comment: See the [Control Transfer Statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120) section of the [Control Flow](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120) chapter of the [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0) book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html) (search for `guard`):

> Early Exit
>
> A guard statement, like an if statement, executes statements depending
>   on the Boolean value of an expression. You use a guard statement to
>   require that a condition must be true in order for the code after the
>   guard statement to be executed.

That would be:

```
func function() {
  x = 5

  guard <yourConditionToContinue> else {
    return
  }

  // Code to be executed if <yourConditionToContinue> is met.
}
```